# Encoding of file from WinEdt to TexMaker

Tags: input-encodings, winedt

I have a TeX file that was created, edited and compiled by another person using WinEdt. I now want to keep writing on it using TexMaker, but when I open it with this new editor, these strange symbols appear:

[image: strange_symbols]

How can I find out the encoding that was used in WinEdt, so that these symbols disappear? They are hiding Spanish accents. I have tried downloading WinEdt myself but the same thing happens, it uses UTF-8 encoding by default and the same symbols remain.

Comment: most likely the file was written in latin1 (iso-8859-1) try to load the original version into your editor using that encoding

Comment: winedt has a tool to convert files from ansi/latin1 to utf8.